# bind-attr with Controller property

Tags: ember.js, controller

Consider the following code:

Handlebars template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="items">
    <div {{bind-attr class="isArchiveActive:active"}}>
        Will be highlighted if an archived item is active.
    </div>
    <ul class="archived-items">
        {{#each}}
            <li {{bind-attr class="isActive:active"}}>
                <button {{action "activate" this}}>Activate</button>
                <button {{action "deactivate" this}}>Deactivate</button>
            </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

Controller:

```
App.ItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        activate: function(item) {
            item.set('isActive', true);
        },
        deactivate: function(item) {
            item.set('isActive', false);
        }
    },
    isActive: false,
    isArchiveActive: function() {
        var items = this.filterBy('isArchived', true).filterBy('isActive', true);
        return items.length > 0;
    }
});
```

Model:

```
App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    isArchived: DS.attr('boolean')
});

App.Item.FIXTURES = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'Geometry',
    isArchived: true
}];
```

Currently, when this code runs, the `bind-attr` inside the `{{#each}}` blocks update the active class correctly when toggling the "Activate" and "Deactivate" buttons. However, the `bind-attr` outside only works onLoad and does not update dynamically.

Is there a way to bind the controller attributes and have it update on the fly.

Comment: You could use a single button with {{action 'toggleActive' this}} and, inside your actions hash, toggleActive: function(item) { item.toggleProperty('isActive')},

Comment: My issue was not toggling the `isActive` property, but rather binding a computed property.

Comment: I know, but it would clean up your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed your code(**demo with css, templates etc. - [emberjs.jsbin.com](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/rekiboci/3#/items)**). You have to make `controller.isArchiveActive` computed property so it reacts on `item.isActive` property changes:

```
isArchiveActive: function() {
    var items = this.filterBy('isArchived', true).filterBy('isActive', true);
    return items.length > 0;
}.property('model.@each.isActive')
```

Full app.js code(I needed to write more code so I could test it, you probably have different routes etc.):

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('items');
});

App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    isArchived: DS.attr('boolean')
});

App.Item.FIXTURES = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'Geometry',
    isArchived: true
},
{
    id: 2,
    title: 'AnotherArchived',
    isArchived: true
},
{
    id: 3,
    title: 'SomethingOtherNotArchived',
    isArchived: false
}];

App.ItemsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('item');
    }
});

App.ItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        activate: function(item) {
            item.set('isActive', true);
        },
        deactivate: function(item) {
            item.set('isActive', false);
        }
    },
    isActive: false,
    isArchiveActive: function() {
        var items = this.filterBy('isArchived', true).filterBy('isActive', true);
        return items.length > 0;
    }.property('model.@each.isActive')
});
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for a running example as well. I had tried making it a computed property earlier, but I was attaching it with both `isArchived` and `isActive`. Either my syntax was wrong or it wasn't working with both. To bind it with more properties, would you just chain it? Like `.property('...').property('...')`.

Comment: According to [http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/) you can use `.property('firstProperty', 'secondProperty')`, so this works([demo](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/rekiboci/4#/items) - deactivate button sets `isArchived` property to `false`): `.property('model.@each.isActive', 'model.@each.isArchived')`.